# Django data migration FieldError

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    kind = models.ForeignKey('UserKind', blank=True, null=True)
```

when I'm trying to change some users in my migration:

```
def forward(apps, schema):
    User = apps.get_model('user_auth', 'User')
    for user in User.objects.filter(kind__isnull=False):
        # some logic here
```

User.objects.filter(kind__isnull=False) raises django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'kind' into field.

Comment: Have you configured Django to use your custom User model (`AUTH_USER_MODEL`)?

Comment: @petkostas Yes, I do.

Comment: And where is the `UserKind` declared? is it in the same app/module as your User? if not it should be `app.UserKind`

Comment: @petkostas The same app

Comment: Did you try to check in the `manage.py shell` if `type(User)` is indeed your model and not the stock one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in Django which was fixed in 1.8.5 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8.5/)